# Parse Ajax response when it returns an array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ajax

I am trying to parse an ajax response from my query, however, it seems to be returning an array instead of just a single record.

How can I get convert the array into a single response and then parse that so my `measured` variable is only the measured data from the response.

*results*

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        company_id: 2,
        weightset_id: 1,
        name: 'A.2000',
        nominal: '2000.0',
        measured: '1999.9998',
        uncertainty: '0.002',
        precedence: 1,
        edited_by: null,
        created_by: 2,
        drift: 2,
        created_at: '2018-09-18T20:00:13.600Z',
        updated_at: '2018-09-18T20:42:31.804Z',
    },
];
```

*javascript*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".repeatability_weight").on('change', function(){
     var input = $(this)
     var val = input.val()? input.val() : 0;

     var applied_weight = val

     window.alert(applied_weight);

       $.ajax({
        url: '<%= weightsets_weight_find_path %>', 
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'weight_id': applied_weight},

       success: function(response) 
            {
              var response = JSON.parse(response)
              var measured = response.measured
              console.log(response)
            }
      })   

  window.alert(measured)

  var res = $(".resolution").data("resolution")

  var measured = measured.toFixed(res)

  $(this).closest('tr').find('.repeatability_measured')[0].textContent = measured;


})

</script>
```

Comment: You could do `response = JSON.parse(response)[0]` but the cause of the problem is that your api is returning array because there could maybe be multiple items. If this is not the case then you should probably still fix this in your api (so do not solve it with JavaScript).

Comment: No need to "convert" anything, just read the relevant value from the correct index of the array: `var measured = response[0].measured`. Very standard JavaScript stuff. But consider HMR's remarks - if the API is returning an array, it implies there could be multiple results (unless the API is just badly designed) - so maybe you need to redesign your code/UI to take account of that possibility.

Comment: Also note that all the code from `window.alert(measured)` onwards needs be inside your "success" function, otherwise it will be executed before the AJAX call has returned with the value, and therefore won't do anything useful - if you weren't aware, that's because AJAX calls are _asynchronous_.

Comment: If you are expecting a JSON object, why don't you just use `$.getJSON` instead of the generic `$.ajax` method? the success function param `response` will already by parsed as a JSON object.

Comment: @arieljuod forgive me for asking as I am learning as I create this but could you show me how I would put that together?

Comment: @ChrisNash I have posted an answer with the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.getJSON` and it takes care of parsing the result, you have to respond to the json format with a `.json` view

```
$(".repeatability_weight").on('change', function(){
  /* code code code */

  url = '<%= weightsets_weight_find_path %>';
  data = {weight_id: applied_weight}

  $.getJSON(url, data, function(data) {
    console.log(data) //this should print the array on the console
    var measured = data[0].measured //note the [0], you want the first element of the array to get the `measured` property
    console.log(measured)
  })

  /* the rest of your code */
})
```

check the docs for more details https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score -1):

If the server is returning in string format

```
'[{"id":1,"company_id":2,"weightset_id":1,"name":"A.2000","nominal":"2000.0","measured":"1999.9998","uncertainty":"0.002","precedence":1,"edited_by":null,"created_by":2,"drift":2,"created_at":"2018-09-18T20:00:13.600Z","updated_at":"2018-09-18T20:42:31.804Z"}]'
```

then use

```
var resp = JSON.parse(response);
var measured = resp[0].measured;
```

If server is returning an array directly

```
[{"id":1,"company_id":2,"weightset_id":1,"name":"A.2000","nominal":"2000.0","measured":"1999.9998","uncertainty":"0.002","precedence":1,"edited_by":null,"created_by":2,"drift":2,"created_at":"2018-09-18T20:00:13.600Z","updated_at":"2018-09-18T20:42:31.804Z"}]
```

then access is directly, you don't need to parse it again.

```
var measured = response[0].measured;
```

edit:
As mentioned by ADyson, server always returns a string. It depends on your needs, how you need to parse the data. If you have parsed data in hand(like how setting the datatype:json when using jquery), you can use it directly otherwise JSON.parse is always there.

Comment: "If server is returning an array directly"...a server cannot return a JS object directly, it can only return a textual response. So it'll be JSON. Therefore you have to parse it. You can either parse it manually (as OP is already doing) or since $.ajax is being used you can specify the `dataType: "json"` option - this just causes jQuery to parse the response before passing to the success callback, so it appears as an object already. There is no such thing as the "server returning an array directly", it's always some sort of text.

Comment: P.S. The first part of your answer is fine, but downvoted for talking nonsense in the second part, sorry.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say that if you have the response variable as an array already, you don't need to parse the data, exactly what you said in your first comment. Sorry for that misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem, if you edit your answer to be more technically accurate then I'm happy to change my vote.

Comment: Thanks both @ADyson and amit, after I've been banging my head all morning on how to convert it and after I typed this question and went for a walk it occurred to me to read in the relevant array index I wanted.

If I set the the ajax request to async: false, would it run "in order" and if so how do I take my measured variable out of the ajax success function. Thanks again

Comment: yes it would but `async:false` is deprecated because it causes horrible user experience (locking the whole browser UI while the request is running, so people think it's crashed if the request takes a bit longer than normal) and you can expect it to be removed from browsers in the future. So it's not a good idea to use that. Instead, learn to work with the async-ness and move everything which depends on `measured` into the "success" function, or into a function which you then call from the "success" and pass the "measured" variable into it. Promise-based syntax is also an option if preferred.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. I take it because of the fact I have moved the line `$(this).closest('tr').find('.repeatability_measured')[0].textContent = measured;` into the success funciton it will no longer work as `this` is no longer the owner of the function?

Comment: sorry yes, that's right, you would need to assign `this` to another variable before entering the ajax call, and then use that variable within "success".

Comment: By the way, small thing, if you want to keep it a bit more consistently using jQuery syntax you could swap `[0].textContent = measured` for `.text(measured)`

Comment: Thanks I changed it to input.closest('tr').find('.repeatability_measured').text(measured);